# Spring Cloud Config unable to get correct values

Tags: java, spring-cloud-config

I am unable to get the value I am expecting, An exception is thrown at this line `@Value("${message:this-is-class-value}")`.

**SERVER SIDE**

pom.xml

```
 <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-config-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

src/main/resources/application.properties

```
server.port=8888
spring.application.name=config-service
spring.cloud.config.server.git.uri=file:///C:/config
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*
spring.security.user.name=root
spring.security.user.password=abc123
```

Application class

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.cloud.config.server.EnableConfigServer;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableConfigServer
public class ConfigServiceApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ConfigServiceApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Local git folder

Configurations files with the same property but the different value to detect

```
c:/config/application.properties
c:/config/api-gateway.properties
c:/config/api-gateway-PROD.properties
```

output while server startup

```
Completed initialization in 5 ms
WARN : Could not merge remote for master remote: null
INFO : o.s.c.c.s.e.NativeEnvironmentRepository  : Adding property source: file:/C:/config/application.properties
```

if I access this url 
`http://localhost:8888/api-gateway/PROD`
console output is as follows

```
WARN : Could not merge remote for master remote: null
INFO : o.s.c.c.s.e.NativeEnvironmentRepository  : Adding property source: file:/C:/config/api-gateway-PROD.properties
INFO : o.s.c.c.s.e.NativeEnvironmentRepository : Adding property source: file:/C:/config/api-gateway.properties
INFO : o.s.c.c.s.e.NativeEnvironmentRepository  : Adding property source: file:/C:/config/application.properties
```

**CLIENT SIDE (Separate Project)**

pom.xml

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-zuul</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Application class

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableZuulProxy
@EnableDiscoveryClient
public class ApiGatewayApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ApiGatewayApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Controller

```
@RestController
public class SettingsController {
    @Value("${message:this-is-class-value}")
    String name = "World";

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String home() {
        return "Hello " + name;
    }
}
```

resources/application.yml

```
server:
  port: 8282
spring:
  application:
    name: api-gateway
eureka:
  instance:
    preferIpAddress: true
  client:
    registerWithEureka: true
    fetchRegistry: true
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: ${EUREKA_URI:http://localhost:8761/eureka}
```

resources/bootstrap.yml

```
spring:
  profiles:
    active: PROD
  cloud:
    config:
      name: api-gateway
      uri: http://localhost:8888/
      username: root
      password: abc123
management:
  endpoints:
    web:
      exposure:
        include: refresh
```

Console output

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'settingsController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type [java.util.LinkedHashMap<?, ?>] to type [java.lang.String]

Caused by: org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type [java.util.LinkedHashMap<?, ?>] to type [java.lang.String]
```

Please do let me know if anything else is required.

Answer (score 0):

add ***message=Hello from property file1*** in src/main/resources/application.properties. Or if you want to read this property from c:/config/application.properties or c:/config/config-service.properties you need to configure external configuration file by using **@ConfigurationProperties** annotation.

Comment: Could you please guide me here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66922674/unable-to-fetch-property-value-from-the-config-server?

Answer (score 0):

Looks, you are trying to use the @Value annotation on controller class which resides in your Cloud config server application. While the concept is like cloud config server application will be the provider to other applications and it can provide the properties from git or local file system (configuration) to requester client application. Other applications will connect to your config server application by providing it's URL, application name and profile for which it want to get the properties. You can check below URL for cloud config server and client application.
https://www.thetechnojournals.com/2019/10/spring-cloud-config.html

Your cloud config server has security configuration as below.
spring.security.user.name=root
spring.security.user.password=abc123

You client configuration doesn't provide any security configuration which is causing 401 error in your logs.

To solve this issue please do below changes to your client configuration.

**Client configuration:**

```
spring:
  profiles:
    active: PROD
  cloud:
    config:
      name: api-gateway
      uri: http://localhost:8888/
      username: root
      password: abc123
```

Comment: I did create a separate project and also added this boostrap.yml file but I still see default message

Comment: I can access this url
`http://localhost:8888/clientProjectName/PROD/master` but my client app does not see these from config server

Comment: can you please show your client configuration for config server connection?

Comment: To solve this issue, I have edited my answer. Hopefully it should resolve your issue.

Comment: `Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type [java.util.LinkedHashMap<?, ?>] to type [java.lang.String]` I guess it has problem @Value field

Comment: Hello @AshokPrajapati, I have similar issue, when you meant to have below changes in client configuration, do you mean to add security details in both application.yml & bootstrap.yml ?

Comment: Hi @PHPAvenger Let me know if you were able to resolve the issue and what's the fix for it ?

Comment: @SantoshRaviteja You need to keep all cloud configurations in bootstrap.yml.